# Iterate without for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

This must be trivial.

I want to calculate the following.

100*((1 + r)**n), for n = 0, 1, 2, ..., N

I used the following.

````
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([c0, range(5)], lambda w,r: w*(1.02**r)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'float' and 'range'```
````

Comment: What does `c0` represent in your code?

Comment: And what does r represent in your formula? Your formula looks like it should be a simple list comprehension, like in @AliSoliman's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be a list comprehension

```
[100*((1 + r)**n) for n in range(N)]
```

This would give a list for each value of n, 0 <= n < N

Answer (score 2):

You need to unpack (star, `*`) your `range`:

```
list(itertools.accumulate([c0, *range(5)], lambda w,r: w*(1.02**r)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the range to build the list of numbers; putting range(5) into the list won't actually build the list:

```
list1 = [c0] + [i for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: `[i for i in range(5)]`-> `list(range(5))`